# When building a Rails Gem, how do I get Rails to include my gem's app/views/ in the ActionView paths that it loads when looking for view partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, actionview

I am building a gem.

You can see my super-simple gem here:
https://github.com/jasonfb/xyz_gem

It's just a shell.

What I want to know today is what tells Rails that it should load my Gem's views, that is, the views in app/views/ when loading partials?

I have a rails app called XyzGemTest (not the gem) that uses the gem via a local path include

I have view that I am rendering simply at HellosController for demonstration.

The view renders this:

```
this is in the app code
<%= render partial: 'hello_world' %>
```

Please note that my partial `hello_world` is inside of my Gem-- at app/views/_hello_world.erb (although I tried also moving it to  app/views/xyz_gem/_hello_world.erb -- see below)

When I load my app, I get this common error:

[image]

As you can see, this blank Rails 6.0 app is trying to load view files from presisely 3 places:
(1) my own app's app/views folder (NOT the gem)
(2) actiontext
(3) actionmailbox

What I'm asking here is what do I need to do to my Gem to make it so that ActionView will include my gem's app/views/ folder in the 'chain' of paths that it looks for?

I tried both app/views/_hello_world.erb and also nesting _hello_world.erb into a folder called xyz_gem like so

[image]

You are welcome to fork & refactor my Github repo above.

Answer (score 0):

Load paths?

application.rb has a line **config.autoload_paths**

I think you need to look there to find your answer